# How to define a foreign key from multiple tables in JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

In JPA, an entity `TimeSeries` is defined like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "time_series")
@NamedQuery(name = "TimeSeries.findAll", query = "SELECT t FROM TimeSeries t")
public class TimeSeries implements Serializable {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  @Id
  @Column(name = "id_time_series", unique = true, nullable = false, precision = 18)
  private Long idTimeSeries;

  @Column(name = "id_element", nullable = false, precision = 18)
  private Long idElement;

  @Column(name = "param_1", precision = 18)
  private Long param1;

  @Column(name = "series_type", nullable = false, precision = 18)
  private Long seriesType;
```

The problem is with the field `id_element`. This id can represent any object for which time series can be defined. For example, if I have table `A` with PK `id_A` and table `B` with PK `id_B`, then `id_element` can be take values from the columns `id_A` from table `A`,or `id_B` from table `B`. The only thing in common between tables `A` and `B` is that they both have an ID and a name.

Is there a way to define `id_element` as a FK coming from table `A` or `B`? I had a look at the `@MappedSuperClass` annotation to relate entities `A` and `B`, but I'm not sure if JPA  will understand that `id_element` relates to entity `A` or `B`.

BTW, the database model is used by Java legacy code. If necessary, I can make minor modifications to the database, as long as the legacy code continues working. We are in a process to migrate the persistence to JPA.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What you describe isn't even possible in a database without involving any java at all. A foreign key must point to a specific table+column. If A and B are in completly different tables with no relationship whatsoever then you cannot define a foreign key that sometimes points to A and sometimes to B.

Comment: I understand that. As I mentioned, A and B share an ID and a name. Could this be used in some way? And if some coding in Java is required, that's OK. Doing so, id_element cannot be a FK, but at least, is is possible to code it to mimic the behavior of a FK? I'm open to any solutions.

Comment: Possible solutions: 1. Instead of having a foreign key from TimeSeries to A/B etc, have the relation mapped in reverse. Give A and B a foreign key that points to the TimeSeries. 2. You could also give A and B a common superclass with its own table and InheritanceType.Joined or InheritanceType.SingleTable and have the foreign key point to that common superclass table.

Comment: @DN1 Please calm down. I'm sorry I offended you by using the term "field" instead of "column". I'm a mathematician, not a computer scientist. And as I mentioned, I can only make minor modifications to the database, as long as the legacy code uses it.

Comment: @OH GOD SPIDERS Thanks. I like your second suggestion. I'll see what I can do with it.

Comment: Yea, it seems like an inheritance problem. Go for it.

Comment: @KarlNicholas The code we're upgrading started in 2000 in Java 1.2. Persistence migration is the first part of the migration plan. The next step will be UI upgrade. Mathematical kernel will follow after that. We're talking about commercial software that must continue to evolve. I know it's tempting to start from scratch, but direction says otherwise...